# Crossover trials standard deviation/error

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

[image: data/question]

Hello, would anyone be able to explain how to get the standard deviation/error using this data? It’s supposedly 0.843 but I’m unsure as to how to get it. Many thanks in advance

Comment: The formula for the standard deviation is right there in your text book. Just plug the values in. The only question you have to watch out for is whether this is a whole population (where you divide by the population size $n$) or just a sample from the population (where you want to divide by one less than the sample size $n - 1$, as it is a better predictor of the standard deviation of the entire population).

Comment: I tried both but I don’t get 0.843 at all, thanks for the reply.

Comment: Who says it is 0.843? I don't see any data on this page at all that would have deviation anywhere near that small. Perhaps they are talking about the ratio of the deviation to the mean?